# Place footnotes in a separate page

Tags: lyx, footnotes

I have searched around a lot but have not been able to find an answer.
How do I put all the footnotes into a separate page in LaTeX/Lyx? I need to place them after the references page.

Comment: Also see the LyX module "Endnote" in Document Settings > Modules

Comment: Thanks for this. I end up using \let\footnote=\endnote for current paper, but I am sure LyX module will be useful in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `endnotes` package. `endnotes` uses `\endnote` instead of `\footnote`, and endnotes are printed with the `\theendnotes` command. Eventually one can use

```
\let\footnote=\endnote
```

To redefine footnotes as endnotes.

**EDIT**

Endnotes are printed a section: The endnotes name (i.e., the title of the section is controlled by) `\notesnames`. It is possible to change it using or removing it:

```
\def\notesname{}
```

The other related instruction is

```
\enoteheading
```

that defines the instructions to treat endnotes as a starred section (i.e., `\section*{\notesname}`) and the heading marks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was what I was looking for. May I ask you if you know how to modify or hide "Notes" section header \theendnotes automatically generates?

Comment: @joon see the edit.